# Error: Module not found al compilar proyecto de Angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy tratando de aplicar Sqlite a mi aplicación móvil con ionic y angular, pero al momento de compilarlo me lanza el siguiente error:

```
 **[ng] Build at: 2023-10-30T21:38:28.874Z - Hash: 826538eb7ce9ea47 - Time: 1987ms
[ng]
[ng] ../../../node_modules/@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx/index.js:2:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'C:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola , quizás esto pueda servir para que le des un vistazo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221726/error-could-not-resolve-module-angular-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install @ionic-native/sqlite --force" y con "npm install @angular/core --force

Comment: Hola, revisa [answer], saludos

Comment: Si tienes que usar `—force `para instalar algo como Angular Core y SQLite me suena a que algo no está bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!! <3